# Clear all HTML fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to clear all textboxes in HTML by calling a javascript function ?

Comment: <input type="reset" value="No javascript method"/>

Comment: +1 if the comment above were an answer

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var ii=0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {
  if (elements[ii].type == "text") {
    elements[ii].value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: You hit the "post" button 2 sec earlier than me... :-)

Comment: Just curious, what's with the "ii"?

Comment: why is this downvoted? somebody upset it's not a jQuery solution?

Comment: I think because it wouldn't reset selects, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.

Comment: I always use ii, rather than the traditional i, because it's impossible to search-replace for single-letter variables.

Comment: @troelskn: That's an interesting way to go about it (using `ii` instead of `i`). I'll keep that in mind. :)

Comment: To clear textareas, add this after the first "for": var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"); for (var ii=0; ii < textareas.length; ii++) { textareas[ii].value = ""; }

Comment: @SashaChedygov: Back in the 80s, I went to a job interview where the interviewer criticised my folio of work because I had chosen single-character variables in a program. I did not get the job, but I bet he's didn't last beyond the 90s either! lol

Answer (score 9):

```
var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    length = fields.length;
while (length--) {
    if (fields[length].type === 'text') { fields[length].value = ''; }
}
```

Comment: This is different/better than "reset" because "reset" would return the text fields to their original page-load values (not necessarily empty) whereas this will clear all the text fields, as the OP wanted.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the work

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    if (inputElements[i].type == 'text') {
        inputElements[i].value = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Scary how similar our solutions are. :)

Comment: I swear I hit the post button and your answer was shown "2 sec ago", mine "0 sec ago" :-)

Comment: my my, 11 years later, your reputations are still similar except that @troelskn has been a few seconds ahead at a few answers :D

Comment: @ARK That's life! :-)

Comment: There's some sort of lesson to be derived from this, I'm sure.

Answer (score 8):

If all you fields started blank you can call the form's reset method:
`document.forms[0].reset()`  (there are usually more elegant ways to get the form handle depending on your specific case).

Answer (score 8):

While not the simplest solution, look into jQuery.  You should be able to do something like:

```
$("input[type=text]").val('');
```

I'm no jQuery expert, though.

Comment: I did say I wasn't an expert.  I've edited it - is it better now?

Answer (score 6):

I think

```
$("input:text").val("");
```

Should work with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Old post..but, with jquery for example:

```
$("input[type=text],textarea,input[type=email]").val('');
```