# clear all ASP label fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to clear all the fields in my .aspx page using javascript (*Should be cross-browser*). The below code is working fine for `TextBox` fields but not for `Label` fields.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "text") {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
    else if (elements[i].type == "label") {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
}
```

Later I saw that HTML is rendering asp.net Labels as `span` so I also tried:

```
else if (elements[i].type == "span") {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Still the Labels are not being cleared. Am I doing something wrong here?

And the other problem is, whenever I refresh the page, the cleared `TextBox` fields are again being populated with the old values.. (really frustrating)

I am trying the above code by referring **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/569357/1577396)**

Please help.

Comment: The `span` is not input with value and type, just innerHtml that you need to clear. If you see you get all elements by tag name "input" the span is span :) Its better to add a common class name to your Label you like to clear, and find all with that class name

Comment: no way to do just simple like with TextBox to Labels also?

Comment: They may be too many more span inside your page - how you distinctive them ? Only with a class name.

Comment: @Aristos yes I kept class name as `label` to all now. Now how to do this?

Comment: Hey I got one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478953/1577396) referring it..

Comment: yes I think is complicate, and the question is correct writen with samples and trys, not worth downvote

Comment: @Manish I dont know what you are saying.. do you mean I am referring the wrong link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern browsers, this will clear all span elements.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span")).forEach(function(e){
    e.innerHTML="";
})
```

If you have applied the class "label" to your ASP labels, then you could be more specific:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".label")).forEach(function(e){
    e.innerHTML="";
})
```

Here is an example that will work in older browsers:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i=0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
    if ("label" == spans[i].className)
        spans[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: This is not working in IE8.. which is must.. I should have mention that before itself.. sorry. BTW, Keep this post for others :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Are you using jQuery or a similar library?

Comment: @Mr_Green OK, added an example using older browsers.  Again, assuming "label" as a class that you've added to your ASP labels.

Answer (score 3):

It is because there are no such types as `label` or `span`. `span` and `label` are completely different tag so you should use `getElementsByTagName` for each of them. The following code should do the trick bu use more clear conditions for the if blocks.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == "text") {
        elements[i].value = "";
    }
}

elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].className == "aspLabel") {
        elements[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}

elements = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].className == "labelClass") {
        elements[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By referring @Bert Evans post I solved my problem.. The problem was that my all label fields including the headings had class name as '*label*'. So if I use the Bert's solution, It will clear all the label fields including headings (which I dont want). Earlier, I thought I can solve this by assigning multiple classes to the fields which I want to clear. something like this

```
<asp:Label class="label clear" ID="lblBoxId" runat="server" Text="Box Id:"></asp:Label>
```

and then Bert's solution,

```
 var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
 for (var i=0; i < spans.length; i++)
 {
     if ("clear" == spans[i].className)  //replacing 'label' with 'clear'
        spans[i].innerHTML = "";
 }
```

This doesn't solve the problem. but when I used combination of both classes, the problem solved :).

```
  if ("label clear" == spans[i].className)  //using combination of classes as condition
```

This maybe simple but I really wasted my precious time understanding it. So I shared :)

**EDIT**: Can also be solved using simple `indexOf()`

```
if (spans[i].className.indexOf("clear") != -1)   //not tested
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using html label or span with runat="server", then you will not be facing any problem with different rendering of control in different browsers

```
<label id="lblMyLabel" runat="server"></label>
```

or

```
<span id="spMySpan" runat="server"></span>
```

and this code should work then

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: I learnt now that, If a asp:label has `associated ID` then it renders as `<label>` or else if it doesnot have a `associated ID` then it renders as `<span>`. so, I think there is no need to change as you mentioned.. and use `innerHTML` instead of `value` because they are not input fields :).