# How can I clear all texts after pushing submit button in a form?

Tags: javascript, php, filter, fill

I'm making a filter in PHP but I need javascript to fill the form after pushing submit button (for people to see what they entered in the form).

To do so, I did this:

```
<form method="post">
    <div style="display:flex;margin-top:20px;">

        <input name="surfMin" id="surfMin" type="text" style="height: 35px;width: calc(100%/3);" placeholder="min surface">
        <input name="surfMax" id="surfMax" type="text" style="height: 35px;width: calc(100%/3);" placeholder="max surface">
        <input name="prix" id="prix" type="text" style="height: 35px;width: calc(100%/3);" placeholder="price">
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;margin-top:30px;text-align: center;">
        <input id="button" style="width: 25%;height: 35px;background: #dc3545;color:white;" type="submit" name="search" />
    </div></form>

if (isset($_POST['surfMin']))

    print "  <script>
            document.getElementById('surfMin').value = '" . $_POST['surfMin'] . "' 
        </script>";

if (isset($_POST['surfMax']))

    print "  <script>
                document.getElementById('surfMax').value = '" . $_POST['surfMax'] . "' 
            </script>";

if (isset($_POST['prix']))

    print "  <script>
                document.getElementById('prix').value = '" . $_POST['prix'] . "' 
            </script>";
```

This code is working perfectly except if I try to fill again new values in the form. The last values stayed in. I want to delete all values if we click on any input to be capable of to refill it.

How can I to do so ?

Comment: This may help for jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form

.And this other one on pure JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569357/clear-all-html-fields-using-javascript

Comment: _Side note:_ Why don't you just put the default values from PHP into the HTML inputs directly instead of doing it through JS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm editing my answer, because I finally understand your question.

You want the values of the form to still be displayed even after the form has been submitted, **BUT** once it's been submitted, you want the next edit attempt to clear out all its data.

Here is your solution:

```html
<form>
    <input name="name" />
    <input name="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');

    // Add event listener for once the form is submitted
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Once submitted, add event listener to the form for the next edit
        function onKeyUp({ target }) {
            // Grab character user typed so it's not lost
            const char = target.value[target.value.length - 1];

            // Clear out all the form inputs
            [...inputs].forEach((input) => (input.value = ''));

            // Put the typed character back in its place
            target.value = char;

            // Remove this event listener now
            form.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
        }

        form.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    });
</script>
```

Also, maybe it could help you, but you can get a nice clean object with all your form's inputs in object format (as long as each input has a `name` attribute) using `FormData`:

```html
<form>
    <input name="name" />
    <input name="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');

    // Add event listener for once the form is submitted
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const jsonFormData = Object.fromEntries([...new FormData(e.target)]);

        console.log(jsonFormData);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi mstephen19. Thank's for the answer and especially because you understood my question. BRAVO !!!  (It was complicated to explain). Anyway, I'm going to try what you wrote. Bye.

Comment: Hi. I tried the code.  I adapted it to my website and it worked perfectly. Thank's again mstephen19 and all of you actually to your answer. See you soon. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reset button after the submit button

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
```

By the way, your code is vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Hi. Thank's Leao for the comment but in my version, I added the function "htmlspecialchars" to all the $_POST values.